# Unix time convert to Date in Azure stream analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I'm using stream analytics to process some RFID data in realtime. The events from the RFID reader is sending to event hub as an input. Right now I'm facing a problem that the time in events is in UNIX time format, which looks like "TimeStamp":1460471242.22402,"  It's very strange that when I test the query(Not start the job but use the sample data from input), the UNIX time changed to "2016-04-12T14:48:00.0000000Z" , but when I start the SA job, it failed and said that the column 'timestamp' doesn't conforms to ISO 8601 standard. Is there any way to convert UNIX time to standard date format in SA without change the input raw data?
My query is simple like:
SELECT
    EPCValue, Antenna,  System.TimeStamp AS Time
    INTO
    dataoutput
FROM
    datainput timestamp by TimeStamp

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the sample from this page. It describes how to convert UNIX time to SQL datetime format
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt573293.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, I have tried this but it doesn't work, I changed my query to this:SELECT
      System.Timestamp as Time,
      Antenna
      FROM datainput TIMESTAMP BY DATEADD(millisecond, epochtime, '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z').  The error massege is "Dropping events due to improper timestamps. Stream Analytics only supports ISO8601 format for DateTime values"  Do you have an idea of this? Did I do wrong anywhere?

Comment: I've just realized there is a limitation that DATEADD can only use integer type as argument. Can yup please make sure your data is of integer type? We will make fixes to make error message more specific as well as we will look into changing DATEADD to accept float argument.

Comment: You can also use this as a temporary workaround to convert value into integer inside Stream Analytics: SELECT System.Timestamp as Time, Antenna FROM inputeh 
TIMESTAMP BY DATEADD(millisecond, CAST(CAST(epochtime AS float) as bigint), '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')